# Product Categories are empty in the admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I use magento API to add products to my store.
the products fall in under their categories correctly in the fronted, however, when I go to the admin panel under **Catalog -> Manage Category**, I do not see any of the products under their categories, all the categories are empty.
Categories and sub categories are showing in the Manage Category view, but the products are not showing under the categories.
I tries refreshing the cache but that didn't help, any suggestions here??

Comment: pls check the option selected in "Store view" dropdown on the left side of the screen.. Change it to All store views and see again!

Comment: @laith Can we see the code?